# aws-sdk go, function works but getting internal server error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm using the serverless framwework to build a simple function with aws-go. My function works but whenever I try to make a GET request I get an `internal server error`

My function is a copy paste from the `aws-sdk` documentation

```
input := &rds.ModifyDBClusterSnapshotAttributeInput{
    AttributeName:               aws.String("restore"),
    DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier: aws.String("foobar"),
    ValuesToAdd: []*string{
        aws.String("123456789"),
    },
    ValuesToRemove: []*string{
        aws.String("all"),
    },
}

result, err := svc.ModifyDBClusterSnapshotAttribute(input)
if err != nil {
    if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        switch aerr.Code() {
        case rds.ErrCodeDBClusterSnapshotNotFoundFault:
            fmt.Println(rds.ErrCodeDBClusterSnapshotNotFoundFault, aerr.Error())
        case rds.ErrCodeInvalidDBClusterSnapshotStateFault:
            fmt.Println(rds.ErrCodeInvalidDBClusterSnapshotStateFault, aerr.Error())
        case rds.ErrCodeSharedSnapshotQuotaExceededFault:
            fmt.Println(rds.ErrCodeSharedSnapshotQuotaExceededFault, aerr.Error())
        default:
            fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
        }
    } else {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    return
}

fmt.Println(result)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @GiamPy I'm getting a 502

Comment: If it's integrated via api gateway you need to provide a proper response at your lambda function, e.g: `{"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps({"success":true})}`